# Error while creating react native project using yarn "Error: Command failed: yarn init -y"

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg

Facing this issue ever since I installed yarn don't know what the problem is as creating my react native project using npm  `npx react-native init SomePoject --npm`  works just fine.

Whereas when i try it without specifying to use npm  `npx react-native init SomeProject` it gives this error:

Link to screen shot of error it will tell all its story

[image: 1]

Comment: What node version you are using?

Comment: try reinstalling yarn, without sudo